# Org-mode completion: remapping `M-TAB`

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, completion

(Using latest version of Spacemacs, on Windows)

I'm new to org-mode and really need to figure out how to get completion working for stuff like tags and `#+` options. Apparently org uses `pcomplete` as the completion backend. Indeed `M-x pcomplete` (helm) does offer a buffer with long list of completions for `#+`.

The manual says various completions are accessible with `TAB` and `M-TAB`. `TAB` works fine for blocks. But `M-TAB` is alt-tab in Windows and therefore cannot possibly be used. I think most Linux DE's also use `alt-tab` for window switching, while the dedicated `Meta` key has not been seen on keyboards for ages — which really makes me wonder why is this is *still* the default for such an important feature as completion.

I tried `(global-set-key (kbd "<f1> 1") (kbd "M-<TAB>"))` and `(global-set-key (kbd "<f1> 1") (kbd "M-TAB"))`. Now `<f1> 1` is mapped to "Keyboard macro", but it doesn't invoke `pcomplete` (or anything else in org).

So: **How do you remap `M-TAB`?**

(Note: I looked for an answer online and the stuff I tried is what I found. Doesn't seem to work)

(Note2: I've tried `ESC TAB` and `C-M-i` (since helm says that's what `M-TAB` is mapped to), but these keys just jump the cursor to the next line and nothing else.)

Comment: These are two separate questions.  Please ask them in two separate posts (but do some searching on the keybinding question about `M-TAB`, as it's almost surely a duplicate).

Comment: Done. That meta key symbol next to your username is very apropos.

Comment: In practice, `Meta` is just `Alt` these days -- the language is a holdover from Emacs's venerable origins.  If I understand correctly, you want to find a way to call the command bound to `M-TAB` with a different keybinding, correct?  The most straightforward thing to do is to find out what command that is (the manual should tell you), and then [bind that command to a different key](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html).

Comment: Yeah but M-TAB is hijacked by most operating systems for task switching. Should I be binding `pcomplete` then? Can't you just rebind the key itself, as I tried above? How do you personally use completion in org (if you do)?

Comment: Just use `ESC TAB` instead of `M-TAB` on Windows.

Comment: See note2. Might be a spacemacs issue. Does `ESC TAB` bring up `pcomplete` for you?

Answer (score 2):

See the Info page ["(emacs) Windows Keyboard"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Keyboard.html#Windows-Keyboard) for an explanation on the expression `(w32-register-hot-key [M-tab])`

On those systems where I used that hot-key for Emacs I use Windows-Tab or Windows- to switch to other apps.